# Copy textbox from one frame to another frame

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is simple, but everything I keep finding keeps wanting to make it into the same page, not cross frames.

I'm trying to make data entry easier by being able to type everything on a local page, press a button (javascript) and it fills the other page across the iframe. I don't have access to server side coding since this will be ran on the desktop.

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name1" id="id1" VALUE="" MAXLENGTH="3" SIZE="3">
```

Is there a way to create a textbox in iframe 1 and allow javascript at the press of a button to auto fill this field in iframe2?

Thanks all.

Edit: Only client-side programming like javascript can work. It is basically like taking information keyed on a local webpage (on the desktop) that also is opened with the mainpage (www.domain.com) and it carries the information over.

So if I type in John Smith on my .htm file, it would carry that to the other textbox with John Smith.

Comment: I'm up for any additional suggestions as well that might allow this method to work if Iframes isn't the option.

Comment: Would both iframes and the hosting web page be on the same domain?

Comment: It would be ran from the desktop. So only client-side programming allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear which environment that you're facing (with same domain or not). I'd suggest that you can use ajax to send and receive text data. Here are steps to implement.

1. Create two server interface; one is,for example, "puttext", another is "gettext".
2. You can either use session or hash to identify a user.
3. Once a user click a Send button, it calls puttext with text data via Ajax call.
4. Receiver page has a timer checking if there is anything coming.
5. When result of "gettext" is not null, copy it into textbox.

However, it'll be much easier if two pages are in the same domain by calling parent scripts.

Comment: The main issue is that it can only be client side programming such as javascript. I won't be loading this on a domain. So, the local page would be nested in the same window (iframe) with the website we key our orders. Ideally, I'd like to be able to make a textbox that carries over from my page and copies into the textbox with the same name on the www.page.   Say, if you were ordering something online, and you wanted a local page that you could type in an address and contact information. You press the button, and it carries it over.